# Building an array of dictionary items in YAML?

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

Basically trying to something in yaml that could be done using this json:

```
{
models:
 [
  { 
    model: "a"
    type: "x"
    #bunch of properties...
  },
  {
    model: "b"
    type: "y"
    #bunch of properties...
  }
 ]
}
```

So far this is what I have, it does not work because I am repeating my `model` key but what can be a proper way to do that by keeping that `model` key word?

```
models:
 model:
  type: "x"
  #bunch of properties...
 model:
  type: "y"
  #bunch of properties...
```

Comment: Have you tried loading your JSON code into a native data structure (in your language of choice), then using a YAML library to serialize that structure? Always easier to let the machine do the work for you. :)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Use a dash to start a new list element:

```
models:
 - model: "a"
   type: "x"
   #bunch of properties...
 - model: "b"
   type: "y"
   #bunch of properties...
```

Answer (score 96):

You probably have been looking at YAML for too long because that what you call JSON in your post isn't, it is more a half-and-half of YAML and JSON. Lets skip the fact that JSON doesn't allow comments starting with a `#`, you should quote the strings that are keys and you should put `,` between elements in mapping:

```
{
"models":
 [
  {
    "model": "a",
    "type": "x"
  },
  {
    "model": "b",
    "type": "y"
  }
 ]
}
```

**That** is correct JSON as well as it is YAML, because YAML is a superset of JSON.
You can e.g. check that online at this [YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/).

You can convert it to the block-style you seem to prefer as YAML using  [ruamel.yaml.cmd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (based on my enhanced version of PyYAML: `pip install ruamel.yaml.cmd`). You can use its commandline utility to convert JSON to block YAML (in version 0.9.1 you can also force flow style):

```
yaml json in.json
```

which gets you:

```
models:
- model: a
  type: x
- model: b
  type: y
```

There are some online resources that allow you to do the above, but as with any of such services, don't use them for anything important (like the list of credit-card numbers and passwords).

Comment: This really *is* the better answer. I'm a bit embarrassed to have mine accepted.

Comment: Thanks, but looking at the upvote counts, obviously your answer serves a need and mine doesn't.

Comment: I'm chalking it down to the "what folks want" vs "what folks need" dichotomy. The points you're making here are important ones -- someone who generates YAML using a tool such as JQ and then converts it to block-style if they prefer with the tools you link is going to have a much more robust solution than someone who tries to hand-generate text to fit an example.

Comment: OP did not want to convert `JSON` to `YAML` in the first place.
He wanted an array of dicts in `YAML` and that's what most other people coming here want as well (i assume).

Comment: @johnson The text above the first example of the OP states "this JSON" , then proceeds to provide literal style YAML he wants to get that converted to. Even if the OP did not provide valid JSON, (s)he called it that, so I think you should assume that then wanted JSON -> YAML conversion. YAML has `sequences` and `mappings`. Those collection types are called `array` and `object` in JSON and `list` resp. `dict` in Python. So if they come here with the expectation of getting an "array of dicts in YAML" as you assume, they should probably get their terminology straightened out.

Comment: The quote is longer: "**could** be done using this JSON". He only uses `JSON` as a means of representation for the desired result. The fact that it's not even valid emphasizes that.